# Save-function in R

Tags: r, save, environment

I would like to use a custom function to save my R functions to a file. I made the following:

```
savefun <- function(){
  rm(list = setdiff(ls(), lsf.str())) # to remove all variables first
  save.image(paste0("fun",".RData"))
}
```

Now the 2 lines do work in `global`, but not within the function.

Test by making some random variables:

```
x <- 1243
y <- 39934934
```

Those are not deleted by `rm(list = setdiff(ls(), lsf.str()))`. I tried to fix it by changing the environment, but it doesn't work.

Any hints?

Comment: what's wrong with `save(list=lsf.str(),file="fun.RData")` ???

Comment: Take a look at the `envir` argument in `rm`

Comment: I did use `envir`. But it doesn't work. What is the right argument? It's not `.GlobalEnv`

Comment: @BenBolker Nothing wrong with it. But I use this function so often, I'd like to save the time to set the parameters each time.
Edit: I see how I could rewrite this, but anyways I would like to understand how to handle environments in this case.

Comment: Tangential: This might make a really nice RStudio add-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that all of your searches (`ls`, `lsf.str`, `rm`) look in the global environment:

```
x <- 1243
y <- 39934934

savefun <- function(){
  rm(list = setdiff(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), lsf.str(envir = .GlobalEnv)), envir = .GlobalEnv) # to remove all variables first
  save.image(paste0("fun",".RData"))
}

savefun()
```

Comment: ahh I forgot the last `envir = .GlobalEnv`. Ty!

Answer (score 2):

I still don't see why

```
savefun <- function(file="fun.RData") {
  save(list=lsf.str(envir = .GlobalEnv), file=file)
}
```

wouldn't be more straightforward ... (thanks to @sebastian-c for the `envir=` reminder)

Comment: It _is_ definitely more straight forward. In the comments above I wrote: "Edit: I see how I could rewrite this...", so I knew what you meant. Good improvement to the problem stated, but in the end the major issue was the environment.